# How to let search engines show results from our site?

Tags: php, search, indexing

How do i let search engines index my public content in search results.  I want to do something similar to Yelp.  For example, when you go to yelp and you search for a restaurant you are taken to a public page for that restaurant.  Now when you go to google and type in that resturants name, you will see yelp profile comes up in search result (e.g:  http://www.yelp.com/biz/udupi-palace-san-francisco)

So, say i wanted to do the samething for my site.  How do i do it?

NOte that i am new to this, it might be simple but i am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/website-owner/

Comment: Do you mean how the rating, number of raters, and rough cost are shown in the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Pro Webmasters:

[What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](http://What%20are%20the%20best%20ways%20to%20increase%20your%20site%27s%20position%20in%20Google?)
[SEO: How to Separate Fact from Fiction?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/seo-how-to-separate-fact-from-fiction/13007#13007)